# In PHP, how to get the sum of an associative array with the same key?

Tags: php, html

I was trying to get the sum of values of the same array keys.

Example:

```
array ([1] => 100, [1] => 300, [1] => 400, [2] =>20, [2] =>[40]);
```

I want to get the sum of the array using key `1`. The output would be 800. Is there any function for this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Given that the array you've posted is impossible, because your keys are duplicated, please provide a real example of your array

Comment: You cant have same key index in same level.

Comment: It is impossible to create that kind of array. means it will get only last value for that index not all. you can try using `sub array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data is not valid.

However, you are most likely looking for array_count_values.

```
$ar = array ('first' => 100, 'first' => 300, 'first' => 400, 'second' => 20, 'second' => 40);
print_r(array_count_values($ar));
//Returns array('first' => 800, 'second' => 60)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is not correct but you can use `array_sum()` here is example

```
$a=array (1 => 100, 2 => 300, 3 => 400, 4 =>20, 5 => 40);
echo array_sum($a);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp

In your case you can use `sub array` below is example

```
$a=array (1 => array(100, 300, 400), 2 => array(20, 40));
echo array_sum($a[1]);
```

Comment: Why not show a link to the actual [PHP docs for array sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) rather than to w3schools

Comment: Okay will keep in mind next time :)